# navigate to #id in react while moving between different routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router, href

I have two issues with react router,

1. I created an app with 2 pages, 
   in the header i want to navigate between the pages:
   Header = 'page 1' | 'page2' | 'some #id in page1' | 'some #id in page 2'

I need the header to push the user to the correct page and then scroll to the selected id. 
how can i do that?

2. there is any replacement to <'a href="#id">title in react?

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer - NavLink to = '/page-name#id' :)